# How to find the median of 5 integers in java

Tags: java, median

So I'm new to programming and my teacher wants us to find the medium using if statements (I've asked him but he's not really helping) we haven't learned scanner, loops, arrays, etc.. so all I know is bufferedReader, import.java.io & the basics . I've written out the if statements, but I'm still confused as to how to get it to output the median. The numbers are 1-5 so I know that the median is 3.. Here's what I have for the if statements.

```
        if (num1<num2) 
            System.out.println(num1 + "is less than" + num2);
        if (num1<num3)
            System.out.println(num1 + "is less than" + num3);
        if (num1<num4)
            System.out.println(num1 + "is less than" + num4);
        if (num1<num5)
            System.out.println(num1 + "is less than" + num5);
        if (num2>num1)
            System.out.println(num2 + "is greater than" + num1);    
        if (num2<num3)
            System.out.println(num2 + "is less than" + num3);
        if (num2<num4)
            System.out.println(num2 + "is less than" + num4);
        if (num1<num5)
            System.out.println(num1 + "is less than" + num5);
        if (num3>num1)
            System.out.println(num3 + "is greater than" + num1);
        if (num3>num2)
            System.out.println(num3 + "is greater than" + num2);
        if (num3<num4)
            System.out.println(num3 + "is less than" + num4);
        if (num3<num5)
            System.out.println(num3 + "is less than" + num5);
        if (num4>num1)
            System.out.println(num4 + "is greater than" + num1);
        if (num4>num2)
            System.out.println(num4 + "is greater than" + num2);
        if (num4>num3)
            System.out.println(num4 + "is greater than" + num3);
        if (num4<num5)
            System.out.println(num4 + "is less than" + num5);
        if (num5>num1)
            System.out.println(num5 + "is greater than" + num1);
        if (num5>num2)
            System.out.println(num5 + "is greater than" + num1);
        if (num5>num3)
            System.out.println(num5 + "is greater than" + num3);
        if (num5>num4)
            System.out.println(num5 + "is greater than" + num4);
```

Comment: You've just written if statements that compare all the values (and print out statements). You should think about what the median value means, and how you can find the median value. Then you should print out the single median value.

Comment: you wrote median in title and medium in description. assuming you look for median the answer is num3.

Comment: Why not sort the list? After that, the only `if` statement you need is to determine whether the length of the list is even or odd.

Comment: @DannyFried nobody said they are sorted.

Comment: Also, dumb question: I assume that you know how to calculate the median "by hand"?

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica Yes I know how to calculate the median by hand. I know what the median is I'm just unsure as to what to do after the if statements to get the program to print out 3.

Comment: Just making sure - you'd be surprised at how many people ask questions here without knowing how to do the calculation "by hand."

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to give you the answer; but here are a few tips.

`if` statements can take multiple conditions within the brackets such as:

```
if(a>b && b < 10){...}
```

You can also nest `if` statements within each other:

```
if(a>b){
   if(b<10){...}
}
```

And finally you can have an `else` condition, which will be executed when the condition is not met

```
if(a>b){
   ...
} else {
   ...
}
```

Of course these can all be combined together, nested ifs with multiple conditions and ifs nested into else blocks.

As I said, I don't want to give you the answer to your question as I don't believe that would be the most effective way of learning how to do this; but hopefully this is somewhat insightful and meaningful to your knowledge and understanding.

Answer (score 0):

What if you have 555 numbers? Would you write again all possible combinations? That would literally take days.

Consider using some data structures, for example use array to store your numbers:

```
int[] array = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

The median would be element in the middle, 3.

```
int[] array2 = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
```

The median would be 5 here.

To find median (let's assume the numbers are always in order) you can do something like this:

1. Find out what is the size of array (how many elements you have)
2. If size is odd, then the median is element in the middle
3. If size is even, then the median is a sum of two middle elements divided by 2

Example using array:

```
 int[] array = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
 int size = array.length;
    if (size % 2 == 1) { // odd
        System.out.println("Median: : " + array[size / 2]);
    } else { // even
        int sum = array[size / 2 - 1] + array[size / 2];
        System.out.println("Median: : " + (float) sum / 2);
    }
```

However, I have a feeling that even though this code is very simple, it can still be quite incomprehensible to you. I would strongly advise that you read about arrays and collections in Java - just to save you some time.